# Subscribing for particular form control value changes from a list of form control Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have a form in which i have some field like field A,Field B ,Field C,FieldD and many other field . User's can create as my field as they need .But i want to subscribe for valuechange for field A and fieldB only . I tried with valuechange on the entire form ,its working fine ,but when the form is huge subscribing for valuechange of the entire form is expensive .So is there any way to subscribe selectively for a array of form control.This is want i tried

```js
this.form.subscribe(value => { 
valueA = this.form.get('fieldA').value;
valueB = this.form.get('fieldB').value
})
```

,but this is expensive.Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With angular it's better to you custom NgModel, you define a model object or variable and assign it to  you input like this :

```
prenom: string= 'John';


<input [(ngModel)]="prenom">
```

Comment: The field are created dynamically . I have a check to find whether field A and field B exist .Then want to subscribe for value changes from the list of field created dynamically

Comment: Ok, so the best way is to use FormBuilder and Validators.

This article can helps you:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: is there any way to pass array of formcontrolname in this.form.get method

Answer (score 0):

For **Reactive Form**:

**debounceTime** will make subscription after given milliseconds. *If not required,ignore.*

**distinctUntilChanged** will force subscription only on actual value change. *Ignore if not required.*

```
ngOnInit(){
     this.form.controls['form_control_name']
                .valueChanges
                .debounceTime(MilliSeconds)
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .subscribe(val => {

                  });
}
```

You just subscribe to value changes from required control. For two controls, use as:

```
  this.form.controls['fieldA']...
   this.form.controls['fieldB']...
```